# Reloading MySQL my.cnf changes

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

Do you have to restart MySQL to edit changes? Or can you edit them on the fly and restart MySQL or make the changes inside MySQL?

This server runs 100s of website that are active and I don't really want to bring mysql down for a restart unless I have to.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to change some of the global configuration setting of MySQL There are two ways.

**1.** By Changing variable using `SET GLOBAL` option on running MySQL instance,this does not require server restart we can change variables like **Ex :** I need to set my key buffer to 128 MB

`SET GLOBAL key_buffer_size = 128*1024*1024`;

But using this technique **we can not change or configure all variables and once we restart MySQL these GLOBAL settings are lost.**

**2.** By Changing variables in config file (my.cnf)

**This requires a server restart but changes are permanent.**

Comment: Upvoted. The only mention is: You can combine point 1 and 2. First change the params values by "SET GLOBAL VAR = VAL", then make the same change in the my.cnf. Once the server will be restarted, it will take the values from my.cnf.

Comment: Note that some options can't be changed via method #1 (for example, you can change `key_buffer_size` but not `innodb_buffer_pool_size`). The [MySQL Server Option and Variable Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-option-tables.html) lists these in its summary table with a "No" in the "Dynamic" column.